# is current example causes N+1 in my code?

Tags: laravel, pagination, eloquent

i'm trying to load Category(children's)  to view them in html table and paginate them  like this :

```
// show category children's 

public function show(subCategory $sections)
    {
        // Eager Loading the relationship
       $sections->with('chlidrens');

       // paginate the category - childrens

        $result = $sections->chlidrens()->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(5);

        return view('CompanySections.show',compact('sections','result'));
    }
```

**I have logged** the sql query for the first page like this :

```
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `catnodestreetable` where `id` = ? limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `customers` where `customers`.`id` = ? limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select count(*) as aggregate from `catnodestreetable` where `catnodestreetable`.`node_parent_id` = ? and `catnodestreetable`.`node_parent_id` is not null"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `catnodestreetable` where `catnodestreetable`.`node_parent_id` = ? and `catnodestreetable`.`node_parent_id` is not null order by `created_at` desc limit 5 offset 0"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `categories` where `categories`.`id` = ? limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `clothes` where `clothes`.`item_id` = ? and `clothes`.`item_id` is not null limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `clothes` where `clothes`.`item_id` = ? and `clothes`.`item_id` is not null limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `clothes` where `clothes`.`item_id` = ? and `clothes`.`item_id` is not null limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `clothes` where `clothes`.`item_id` = ? and `clothes`.`item_id` is not null limit 1"} 
[2016-12-28 08:19:20] local.INFO: query {"query":"select * from `clothes` where `clothes`.`item_id` = ? and `clothes`.`item_id` is not null limit 1"}
```

**My question :** is this code cause N+1 !! 
and if it did ... how to fix it ??

Answer (score 0):

The `with` call you do has no further effect. It's not taken into account when you run the relationship method directly. What you can do is the following, using [eager loaded constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads):

```
public function show(subCategory $sections)
{
    $result = $sections->with(['children' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }])->paginate(5);

    return view('CompanySections.show',compact('sections','result'));
}
```